# Add one column from one file to the end of multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

I want to put one column from one file, the column 7,  (i.e motherfile) to the end column of many files (i.e child1.c, chil2.c child3.c and so on)

motherfile

```
  38 WAT1 1    TIP3 OH2  OT    -0.834000       15.9994           0
  39 WAT1 1    TIP3 H1   HT     0.417000        1.0080           0
  40 WAT1 1    TIP3 H2   HT     0.417000        1.0080           0
  41 WAT1 2    TIP3 OH2  OT    -0.834000       15.9994           0
  42 WAT1 2    TIP3 H1   HT     0.417000        1.0080           0
```

child1.c

```
       O        -5.689000       -0.628000      -10.423000
       H        -6.663000       -0.744000      -10.224000
       H        -5.166000       -1.340000       -9.957000
       O        11.405000        3.612000        1.674000
       H        11.331000        4.609000        1.663000
```

child2.c

```
       O        -4.689000       -0.628000      -10.423000
       H        -5.663000       -0.744000      -10.224000
       H        -6.166000       -1.340000       -9.957000
       O        1.4405000        3.612000        1.674000
       H        14.331000        4.609000        1.663000
```

and so on ...

I tried to use

```
awk '{f1 = $0; getline<"motherfile"; print f1, $7}' < child1.c > newchild1.c
```

but this only function to add a column to one file , and I want to put the column to many files.

Note the newchild.c need to be like this one.

```
       O        -5.689000       -0.628000      -10.423000 -0.834000       
       H        -6.663000       -0.744000      -10.224000 0.417000
       H        -5.166000       -1.340000       -9.957000 0.417000
       O        11.405000        3.612000        1.674000 -0.834000
       H        11.331000        4.609000        1.663000 0.417000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk` print statements can be [redirected to a file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_10) using `>` or `>>`.  The following example will read column 7 of the `motherfile` into memory, and write to a new file, pretended with the string `new`, including the saved column.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$7;next}{print$0,a[FNR]>"new"FILENAME}' motherfile
    child1.c child2.c ...
```

Comment: That will fail in some awks since an parenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior. You should always write `print$0,a[FNR]>("new"FILENAME)` instead of `print$0,a[FNR]>"new"FILENAME`. Also unless you're using GNU awk you'll want to close() the previous output file each time you change input file to avoid the "too many simultaneous files open" error. So the robust, portable script would be: `'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$7; next} FNR==1{close(out); out="new"FILENAME} {print $0, a[FNR] > out}'`.